# Changing a function to generate table columns instead of rows

Tags: javascript, json

I have a script that makes a table out of JSON data and it works.
But I need the data to be laid out as Vertical Headings, for brevity. In other words, so that **height** and **date** are in the first column and the corresponding data is to the right.

```js
let PROGWandH = [ { height: "108.0", date: "2019-04-12 00:00:00" },{ height: "108.0", date: "2019-05-13 00:00:00" },{ height: "109.0", date: "2019-06-21 00:00:00" },{ height: "111.5", date: "2019-10-16 00:00:00" },{ height: "111.5", date: "2019-11-15 00:00:00" } ];

function generateTableHead(table, data) {
  let thead = table.createTHead();
  let row = thead.insertRow();
  for (let key of data) {
    let th = document.createElement("th");
    let text = document.createTextNode(key);
    th.appendChild(text);
    row.appendChild(th);
  }
}

function generateTable(table, data) {
  for (let element of data) {
    let row = table.insertRow();
    for (key in element) {
      let cell = row.insertCell();
      let text = document.createTextNode(element[key]);
      cell.appendChild(text);
    }
  }
}

let table = document.querySelector(".PROGWandH");
let data = Object.keys(PROGWandH[0]);
generateTable(table, PROGWandH);
generateTableHead(table, data);
```

```html
<table class="PROGWandH"></table>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: What have you tried to solve this on your own?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I would guess: `<tr><td>height</td><td>108</td><td>108</td><td>109</td>...</tr><tr><td>date</td><td>...</td><td>...</td><td>...</td>...</tr>`

Comment: @Andreas makes sense

Comment: The rows are generated by the javascript. The actual table is completely empty.

Comment: How can I avoid getting downvoted. Are my questions too lame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could loop *N prop* times your Array and use `.reduce()` to recude cells Strings into rows Strings and finally use `Element.insertAdjacentHTML(where, what)`

```js
const arr = [ { height: "108.0", date: "2019-04-12 00:00:00" },{ height: "108.0", date: "2019-05-13 00:00:00" },{ height: "109.0", date: "2019-06-21 00:00:00" },{ height: "111.5", date: "2019-10-16 00:00:00" },{ height: "111.5", date: "2019-11-15 00:00:00" } ];
const rows = Object.keys(arr[0]).reduce((row, pr) => (row += `<tr><th>${pr}</th>${arr.reduce((cells, ob) => (cells += `<td>${ob[pr]}</td>`, cells), '')}</tr>`, row), '');

// Insert once when done.
document.querySelector(".PROGWandH").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', rows);
```

```html
<table class="PROGWandH"></table>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks so much!  I'm generating the height and date via php and modded it to get your solution working.  I'm surprised that your code is so much shorter then the one I was using.  I'm trying to learn ECMAScript 5 and this was a great help!

Comment: @PlanB actually the above can be all rewritten in `for` loops which are more *human*, but yes, if you don't mind my nested `.reduce()` inside those implicit arrow function returns... I can always rewrite a more eyes-friendly version of the above. You're welcome BTW. Happy coding!

Comment: Worked out fine.